# Exponential of Casimir operator

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is meant by exponential of a Casimir operator: $\exp(c(\alpha))$, where $c(\alpha)$ is the Casimir operator of of a representation $\alpha$ of a Lie group $G$?

This is mentioned in Witten's "Quantum Gauge Theories in two dimensions", formula 2.42. By the context of the aforementioned formula, it's supposed to be a number.

Comment: A Casimir element is an element of the centre of the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra. On an irreducible representation, it turns out that any Casimir element acts as a scalar and the exponential of this scalar is what you are looking for. Note there is, in general, an $r$-dimensional space of these Casimir elements where $r$ is the rank of the Lie algebra but since you seem to be working in two dimensions I suspect you are just looking for the standard quadratic Casimir.

Comment: Where can I learn about the fact that Casimir is scalar multiplication on irreducible representations?

Comment: It's a direct result of Schur's Lemma: any operator which commutes with the action of the entire Lie algebra on an irreducible representation is a scalar. See Humphreys' Intro to Lie algebras, Chapter 6 for example.